# 4 GB DDR2 vs 2 GB DDR 3

Tags: windows, memory

I 'm going to purchase new PC. due to my budget limit either i can purchase **2 x 2GB = 4GB DDR 2** or **2 GB Single stick DDR 3**.

Will **2 GB DDR 3** will give almost same performane compare to **4 GB DDR 2**?

In future I will upgrade RAM upto 8 GB

Which option would be better for me for now and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll not even notice a difference between DDR2 and DDR3 speeds. I recommend to go for 4GB DDR2.

Comment: +1: In the long run you're going to see more of a benefit with *fewer* page faults than with *faster* page faults.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're planing to upgrade, get DDR3. The price of DDR3 and DDR2 is generally on par at this point as the industry sifts to DDR3 manufacturing.

If possible (perhaps with a marginally additional cost), try to get 1 DDR3 stick so you can just buy another one to match later instead of replacing both.

DDR3 is the *near* future!

Answer (score 0):

At worst DDR3 is the same speed as DD2; at best it's over twice as fast.

You're RAM capacity requirements are likely to be an issue with most PCs needing 2+ GB for common activities these days

Comment: so should I go for 4GB DDR2?

Comment: My personal computers are split, some have 2GB, some have more. My work laptop has 4GB and I couldn't live without at least 3GB. What do you have now, how much of it do you normally use; and do you anticipate using much more in the near future.

Comment: I will run Adobe Photoshop, Dreamweaver, VLC Media Player, Firefox. "Firefox, Photoshop, Dreamweaver" will be always open at a time on my PC.

Comment: @metal gear solid  Go with 4 GB+, then. More is better in this case.

Comment: Remember only get 8gb if your running 64bit OS or the upgrade is pointless